# Reading after colon

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I am saving some data in a names.txt file.

The format is **discordID: inGameUsername** every user is but on a new line.

Right now when the user runs the command **!link *Username*** then it saves the discordID and their in-game username to the names.txt file.

And when they run **!stats** then there should be two variants if the user's **discordID** exists in names.txt then it looks up the stats of that user with **inGameUser** but when users **discordID** doesn't exist then it sends an error message in chat.

But the problem is I don't know how to do it. How should I look it up and match it?

````js
if (command === "stats") {
    if (!args.length) {
        return message.channel.send("```apache\nIt doesent seem you have linked your account do\n!link {username} \n\nOr if you want to check someone elses stats do \n!stats {username} ```");
    }

    var username = args[0];
    var platform = "origin";
    if (args[1] != undefined) {
        platform = args[1];
    }
    var url = `https://public-api.tracker.gg/v2/apex/standard/profile/${platform}/${username}`;

    var name, RankedPoints, level, rank;

    https
        .get(
            url,
            {
                headers: {
                    "TRN-Api-Key": config.TRN_Token,
                },
            },
            function (res) {
                var data = "";
                res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                    data += chunk.toString();
                });
                res.on("end", function () {
                    var json;

                    try {
                        json = JSON.parse(data);
                        name = args[0];
                        level = json.data.segments[0].stats.level.value;
                        RankedPoints = json.data.segments[0].stats.rankScore.value;

                        if (inRange(RankedPoints, 0, 1200)) {
                            if (inRange(RankedPoints, 0, 300)) {
                                rankNr = " 4";
                            }
                            if (inRange(RankedPoints, 300, 600)) {
                                rankNr = " 3";
                            }
                            if (inRange(RankedPoints, 600, 900)) {
                                rankNr = " 2";
                            }
                            if (inRange(RankedPoints, 900, 1200)) {
                                rankNr = " 1";
                            }
                            rank = "Bronze" + rankNr;
                        }
                        var constructor = "```apache\nName: " + name + "\nLevel: " + level + "\nRank: " + rank + "\nRP: " + RankedPoints + "```";
                        message.channel.send(constructor);
                    } catch (e) {
                        message.channel.send("An error accured: " + e);
                    }
                });
            }
        )
        .on("error", function (err) {
            message.channel.send("An error accured: " + err);
        });
}
````

Comment: Be a bit more specific and detailed with the actual question. Right now you're explaining what you want to accomplish, but not what issue you're having in accomplishing it. Try to put a bit more detail in your question, and you should be much more likely to get an answer!